# Best approach for securing REST services and a web application

Tags: java, rest, spring-security

I´m building a web application which comunicates server and clients through REST services (I´m planning to build a mobile app in mid term).

I´ve used Spring Security in other web applications without REST services. But I´m not sure if that approach is suitable for my scenario.

Is it possible secure both access to web pages and calls to REST services using Spring Security? What would you recommend?

Backend uses Spring Data + Spring MVC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring Security is a good way to secure both REST endpoints and traditional MVC webpages.  The implementation can be similar for both your REST endpoints and MVC routes depending on your requirements.

Spring Security is a popular and effective way to add security to your Spring application.  Since you already have experience with it, you should be able to secure your REST endpoints with relative ease.

Check out this detailed tutorial on securing REST routes with Spring Security to get started: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/5/

Comment: But, as I see in that tutorial, each REST invocation has to provide credentials.
My target is user log in entering user + password and then access to webpages and to REST services don´t require to introduce credentials again.

Comment: A great way to achieve this is with a simple cookie-based authentication.  Look at this article: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/.

Comment: And when you have read the article on cookie-based authentication then you can read this one to see why tokens like that are less than ideal ... http://hueniverse.com/2010/09/29/oauth-bearer-tokens-are-a-terrible-idea/ (bearer tokens are almost identical to cookie based tokens). Have fun - the Internet is a great place :-)